# How to Get Row id in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the row id of different idfeedback

```
SELECT  l.idfeedback_store,
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    feedback_store l
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r;
```

Result

```
idfeedback_store        row_number
1                           1
1                           2
1                           3
2                           4
2                           5
2                           6
2                           7
3                           8
3                           9
3                          10
4                          11
```

Required Result

```
idfeedback_store        row_number
1                           1
1                           2
1                           3
2                           1
2                           2
2                           3
2                           4
3                           1
3                           2
3                           3
4                           1
```

Comment: Please add comment or answer

rather than simply downvote..

please.

Comment: If it is a silly question then please solve and down vote.

Comment: All the queries are good and useful for me

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  l.idfeedback_store, IF(@last=(@last:=idfeedback_store), @curRow := @curRow + 1, @curRow:=1) AS row_number
FROM feedback_store l, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @last:=0) r;
```

Comment: +1 well done ... but you can strip this down do `SELECT  
  idfeedback_store, 
  IF( COALESCE( @last, 0 )=( @last := idfeedback_store ), @curRow := @curRow + 1, @curRow := 1 ) AS row_number
FROM feedback_store;` :o)

Comment: Thanx for upvoting i will remember this query

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to this:

```
select idfeedback_store, group_row_number
from 
(
  select idfeedback_store,
    @num := if(@idfeedback_store = `idfeedback_store`, @num + 1, 1) as group_row_number,
    @idfeedback_store := `idfeedback_store` as dummy
  from feedback_store
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d39e8/5)

Result:

```
| IDFEEDBACK_STORE | GROUP_ROW_NUMBER |
---------------------------------------
|                1 |                1 |
|                1 |                2 |
|                1 |                3 |
|                2 |                1 |
|                2 |                2 |
|                2 |                3 |
|                2 |                4 |
|                3 |                1 |
|                3 |                2 |
|                3 |                3 |
|                4 |                1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
  idfeedback_store,
  @curRow := CASE WHEN @curStore = idfeedback_store THEN @curRow + 1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,
  @curStore := idfeedback_store
FROM
  feedback_store;
```