# Query to solve in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My table have data like this

```
id    from
1    1|Chinmoy Panda|chinmoy|mfsi_chinmoyp
1    532|Narendra Mallik|narendram
1    595|Bhagirathi Panda|bhagirathi

2    1|Chinmoy Panda|chinmoy|mfsi_chinmoyp
2    532|Narendra Mallik|narendram
2    595|Bhagirathi Panda|bhagirathi
2    13|Hemendra Singh|hemendras

3    1|Chinmoy Panda|chinmoy|mfsi_chinmoyp
3    595|Bhagirathi Panda|bhagirathi
3    13|Hemendra Singh|hemendras

4    1|Chinmoy Panda|chinmoy|mfsi_chinmoyp 
4    595|Bhagirathi Panda|bhagirathi

5    595|Bhagirathi Panda|bhagirathi
```

i am trying to this

1. Ignore the 1st row of every id
2. Count w.r.t. from
3. Ignore if the id has one row.

Means

```
Count     from
4         595|Bhagirathi Panda|bhagirathi
2         532|Narendra Mallik|narendram
2         13|Hemendra Singh|hemendras
```

In 1,2,3,4 id 1st row contains chinmay panda.So i ignore that one

Bhagirathi Panda occured 5 times but id 5 having only one row so count is 4.
similarly for others

i tried but unable to find the result

please help me to write the query

(i didn't get what should the title so i write this one. )

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds too procedural.  You need to think about it in terms of sets.

Comment: The concept of "1st" row does not exist in SQL because tables are inherently unordered.  You can have the first row with respect to a particular sort order.  However, there is no obvious sort order by thats the "Chinmoy Pando" line first.  What do you mean by "1st"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you should also look at his previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990596/how-to-get-row-id-in-mysql but apart from that the question could be more precise to this

Comment: @SirRufo . . . Let me repeat.  Tables in SQL are unordered.  MySQL allows you to assign a numeric number on the *output* of a query (as does Oracle).  However, there is *no guarantee* that the output is going to be in the order that data was inserted.  This is particularly true on parallel systems and tables that have deletes as well as inserts.

Comment: @SirRufo . . . MySQL does not guarantee the ordering.  See the explanation here (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4430) and the documentation here (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sorting-rows.html).  I fully understand the question in English, but the words don't translate into SQL.  It is important to understand that sets (i.e. Tables) are not ordered to master SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i don't disagree with you, but this question is not about how to guarantee this order

Comment: @GordonLinoff i don't think we will get a response from OP since he has gone from SO ...

Answer (score 3):

You want a query something like this:

```
select count(*), from
from t
where left(from, 2) <> '1|' and
      t.id in (select id from t group by id having COUNT(*) > 1)
group by from
```

However, because the column names are poorly named (using SQL reserved words), you need to properly quote them.

Also, I'm assuming that by "first" you mean the ones that start with '1|'.

Comment: Just escape columns and tables using `\``

Comment: @SirRufo . . . You are right.  I should have had a "not equal" instead of "equals" for the first comparison.

Comment: what about "Ignore the 1st row of every id"? you did not test on first row but on content

Comment: @SirRufo . . . The definition of first row is unclear from the context.  In all the examples given, the first row starts with "1|".  Without a better definition of "first", there is little else to go on.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so "first" means nothing without specifying the particular ordering.

Comment: i cite `In 1,2,3,4 id 1st row contains chinmay panda.So i ignore that one` because it is 1st row it will be ignored - clear to me

Answer (score 0):

this query will do

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) `count`,
  `from`
FROM (
  SELECT 
    `from`,
    IF( COALESCE( @id, 0 ) = (@id := id) , @curRow := @curRow + 1, @curRow := 1 ) curRow
  FROM
    Table1 ) tmp
WHERE curRow > 1
GROUP BY `from`
ORDER BY `count` desc
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/185f6/6/0)